# Generate a numpy matrix of 2D one-hot encodes from dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that includes courses taken by students every term.

```
data = [['1011', 10, 'Spring-2022','MATH-101'],
        ['1011', 11, 'Summer-2022','BIO-101'],
        ['1011', 12, 'Fall-2022','STAT-102'],
        ['1011', 12, 'Fall-2022','CHEM-101'],
        ['1022', 10, 'Spring-2022','ART-101'],
        ['1022', 10, 'Spring-2022','HIST-102'],
        ['1022', 12, 'Fall-2022','MATH-101'],
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['StudentID', 'TermID', 'Termname','CourseID'])

print(df)

    StudentID   TermID  Termname      CourseID
0   1011        10      Spring-2022   MATH-101
1   1011        11      Summer-2022   BIO-101
2   1011        12      Fall-2022     STAT-102
3   1011        12      Fall-2022     CHEM-101
4   1022        10      Spring-2022   ART-101
5   1022        10      Spring-2022   HIST-102
6   1022        12      Fall-2022     MATH-101
```

I am trying to convert this a 3D numpy array where the shape of the numpy array is
(no of unique students, no of unique terms, no of unique courses).
For my example, the shape would be (2,3,6).

The second and the the 3rd dimension of the numpy array is a 2D one hot encoded matrix where the rows represent all the terms and the columns represent all the courses.

Final output:

```
arr = np.zeros((2,3,6))
arr[0,0,0]=1 #student 1011 Term 10 Course MATH-101
arr[0,1,1]=1 #student 1011 Term 11 Course BIO-101
arr[0,2,2]=1 #student 1011 Term 12 Course STAT-102
arr[0,2,3]=1 #student 1011 Term 12 Course CHEM-101
arr[1,0,4]=1 #student 1022 Term 10 Course ART-101
arr[1,0,5]=1 #student 1022 Term 10 Course HIST-102
arr[1,2,0]=1 #student 1022 Term 12 Course MATH-101

print(arr)

[[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Comment: What is the reason for this? If your actual dataset is much larger, this could become a very expensive matrix to make/store. Though, boolean data will be cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` (or `scipy` to create a sparse matrix) after using [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
cols = ['StudentID', 'TermID', 'CourseID']
pos, idx = zip(*[pd.factorize(df[col]) for col in cols])
arr = np.zeros([len(i) for i in idx], dtype='uint8')
arr[tuple(np.stack(pos))] = 1
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien. Is it possible to create this matrix where the termids and courseids column labels are sorted? I can sort just one column, say termids by sorting the dataframe based on termid column. But I would like to sort the numpy array labels based on both termid and courseid.

Comment: You can sort your dataframe before with something like `df.sort_values(['TermID', 'CourseID'], inplace=True)` or `df1 = df.sort_values(['TermID', 'CourseID'])` if you don't want to modify your original dataframe.

Comment: Sorting would only work on the first column. In our example, print(idx[2]) would display the courses in the below order:
Index(['ART-101', 'HIST-102', 'MATH-101', 'BIO-101', 'CHEM-101', 'STAT-102'], dtype='object')
As we can see, the courses are not ordered, while the terms are ordered.
print(idx[1]):
Index([10, 11, 12], dtype='int64')

Comment: Maybe you want to use `sort=True` as parameter of `pd.factorize` to sort each column?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
a = (pd.crosstab(df['StudentID'],
             [df['CourseID'], df['TermID']])
   .stack(dropna=False)
   .gt(0)
   .to_numpy(dtype=int)
 )

a = a.reshape(df['StudentID'].nunique(), -1, a.shape[1])
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]])
```

If you want a specific order of the columns, use a Categorical or reorder with:

```
a = (pd.crosstab(df['StudentID'],
             [df['CourseID'], df['TermID']])
   .stack(dropna=False)
   .gt(0)[df['CourseID'].unique()]
   .to_numpy(dtype=int)
 )

a = a.reshape(df['StudentID'].nunique(), -1, a.shape[1])
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```